# Problema ao subir e converter arquivos.txt

Tags: r, syntax-error

**Toda vez que eu tento fazer a operação abaixo eu obtenho um erro:**

```
setwd('C:\\Users\\MatheuS\\Documents\\file')

library(readr)


fns = list.files(patt="\\.txt")

sapply(fns, function(x){ assign(gsub("C:\\Users\\MatheusdosSantos\\Documents\\files\\.txt","", x), read.table(x, head=T,sep=";"),
                                envir=.GlobalEnv); NULL})

n <- length(fns)


for (i in 1:n){
  dado1[i] <- read.table(fns[i], head=T,sep=";")
  names(fns[i])[grep("ï..ID", names(fns[i]))] <- "ID"
  write.table(fns[i], dado1, sep="\t", row.names = FALSE, quote=FALSE, na= "", eol = "\r\n")
}


dado1 <- read.table(fns[i], head=T,sep=";")
```

Essa operação sobe (upa) um `arquivo.txt` separado por `;` e exporta ele com o mesmo nome sobrescrevendo o arquivo antigo separando o mesmo agora por `\t` *(tabulação)* e troca o nome.

**Porém sempre dá esse erro:**

```
Error in isOpen(file, "w") : invalid connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(ï..ID = 1:29998, NR_CONTA = c(10000063L,  :
  provided 53 variables to replace 1 variables
2: In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Olha, só umas dúvidas antes. O `sapply ` tá assim mesmo? Porque ele não tá sendo associado a variável nenhuma, ele não tá atualizando `fns`. E as ordens em `write.table` parecem estar erradas. Primeiro vem a tabela, que seria `dado1` e depois o nome `fns[1]`, que é uma string.

Comment: No `sapply` lê os ficheiros e depois no `for` volta a lê-los, porquê? Se só quer mudar o separador de colunas e o nome de uma das colunas (de `"ï..ID"` para `"ID"`), está a complicar imenso. E, já agora, pode explicar porquê mudar o separador de `";"` para `"\t"`?

Answer (score 1):

O código desta resposta foi testado com ficheiros que correspondem ao que sabemos pela descrição na pergunta, não é garantido que funcione sem erros ou adaptação.

Em primeiro lugar, se vai mudar de diretório, obtenha o atual para depois o repor se for necessário.

```
old_dir <- getwd()
setwd('~/Documentos')
```

Agora o processamento. Os ficheiros são lidos todos numa só instrução muito mais simples, o `read.csv2` já tem `sep = ";"` e `header = TRUE` como valores dos respetivos argumentos a passar à função mais geral `read.table`.

```
fns <- list.files(pattern = '\\.txt')

df_list <- lapply(fns, read.csv2)
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(DF){
  i <- grep('\\.\\.ID', names(DF), ignore.case = TRUE)
  names(DF)[i] <- 'ID'
  DF
})
lapply(seq_along(df_list), function(i){
  write.table(df_list[[i]], fns[i], row.names = FALSE, sep = '\t', quote = FALSE, na = '')
})
```

Este código pode ser ainda mais simplificado, executando só um ciclo `lapply` que faz tudo e tem como saída a mesma lista `df_list` com todas as tabelas.

```
fns <- list.files(pattern = '\\.txt')

df_list <- lapply(fns, function(x){
  DF <- read.csv2(x)
  i <- grep('\\.\\.ID', names(DF), ignore.case = TRUE)
  names(DF)[i] <- 'ID'
  write.table(DF, x, row.names = FALSE, sep = '\t', quote = FALSE, na = '')
  DF
})
```

E no fim repor o diretório inicial, se for preciso, tal como disse acima.

```
setwd(old_dir)
```